# Programa en Pascal no acepta la condicion de finalizacion para while

Tags: lista, while, pascal

Tengo como consigna realizar un programa que tome datos de un producto y genere una lista hasta que se ingrese el producto cuyo codigo sea "-1". Ahora, el problema es que al ejecutar el programa e ingresar el codigo -1 , el programa no finaliza, cuando lo ideal seria que el programa termine. Alguna sugerencia? Estoy usando el compilador GDB.

```
program Ejercicio_5;
type
    lista = ^nodo ;                  {Declaracion de la lista}

    producto = record
        codigo : integer;
        descripcion : string;
        stock_actual : integer ;
        stock_minimo : integer ;
        precio : real ;
        end ;
    
    nodo = record
        dato : producto ;
        sig : lista ;
        end ;

procedure agregarAdelante(var L : lista ; p : producto) ;      {Modulo para crear nodo}
var
    aux : lista ;
begin
    new(aux) ;
    aux^.dato := p ;
    aux^.sig := L ;
    L := aux ;
end;

procedure leerProducto(p : producto) ;            {Modulo que lee el registro de producto}
begin
    writeln('Ingrese el codigo del producto') ; readln(p.codigo) ;
    if (p.codigo <> -1) then begin
        writeln('Ingrese la descripcion del producto') ; readln(p.descripcion) ;
        writeln('Ingrese el stock actual del producto') ; readln(p.stock_actual) ;
        writeln('Ingrese el stock minimo del producto') ; readln(p.stock_minimo) ;
        writeln('Ingrese el precio del producto') ; readln(p.precio) ;
    end;
end;

procedure generarLista(var L : lista) ;             {Modulo que crea la lista}
var
    p : producto ;
begin
    leerProducto(p) ;
    while (p.codigo <> -1) do begin
        agregarAdelante(L, p) ;
        leerProducto(p) ;
    end;
end;
var
    L : lista ;

begin                           {Programa principal}
    L := nil ;
    generarLista(L) ;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

En principio el programa parece correcto, simplemente que los valores que modificas dentro del procedimiento `leerProducto`, no están modificados al salir.

Deberías definir el parámetro **"por referencia"** utilizando `VAR`, de esa forma al salir del procedimiento el valor leído dentro, lo tendrás disponible para la comprobación.

La cabecera de la función debería ser esta:

```
procedure leerProducto(var p : producto) ;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias German!